# Can an Angular 2 component style itself?

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 you can include a stylesheet in a component's template. Because of Angular 2's View Encapsulation the styles only apply to the containing elements.

Is there a way to style the component's main tag without putting a surrounding `<div class="component-wrapper"></div>`?

Example plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rANAsR1h9ERBIZV6wuJ8

It has an external css file adding a border and padding to the `<app>` tag, and the template attempts to set a background color.

Comment: have you tried injecting the styles.css in the component instead of using them from index?  check the `styleUrls` property https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ComponentMetadata-class.html

Comment: Yes, using the `styleUrls` property seems to do the same thing. They both end up putting a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` with a rule like `app[_ngcontent-vfb-1]`

Comment: Use `:host`, it's a css thing, not angular, just in case.

Comment: that _ngcontent-vfb-1 should be your `app` tag so its styling itself

Comment: `:host{...}` style becomes `app[_ngcontent-vfb-1] {...}` style (or whatever name your component style compiles to).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You have two options

- Use `host` property

```
@Component({
    selector : 'my-component',
    host : {
        '[style.color]' : "'red'", 
        '[style.background-color]' : 'backgroundColor'
    }
})
class MyComponent {
    backgroundColor: string;
    constructor() {
        this.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
}
```

- Use `styles` property and [`:host`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/)

```
@Component({
    selector : 'my-component',
    styles : [`
        :host {
            color: red;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    `]
})
class MyComponent {}
```

**Note** there's an [odd behavior](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6202) when using `:host` and `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tdvFdbBqAIEMJU6wDl6g?p=preview) with simple examples for both alternatives.

Comment: is it possible to write host styling inside component scss file?

Comment: @olefrank Just use the `:host` selector inside the `.scss` file.

Answer (score 17):

The Best Simple Way!

in your.component.css:

```
:host {
    background-color: blue;
}
```